# Extract/Read emails from Thunderbird/MS Outlook using IMAP and POP in C#

Tags: c#, imap, pop3

I'm a rookie in C#. And I wanted to implement on "how to extract/read email from these clients- Thunderbird/Microsoft Outlook."
I found out various articles on StackExchange and on Code Project as well, but it was all confusing to me.
I'm not asking to provide me a sample code, but a directed understanding of the workflow of what should I carry out step by step to achieve this.

Comment: Link specific parts of that articles, to rewrite them here with a deeper explanation is not really feasible...

Answer (score 0):

Outlook and Thunderbird don't provide anything for reading emails using IMAP or POP3/SMTP protocols. You can use System.Net namespace classes to access emails on the server using the mentioned protocols. Refer to the Mohair's answer for the sample code.

Also you may consider automating Outlook. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/201096) for more information.